# How to log Google Drive File Names to Google Sheets using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

So I am trying to log files (and their Id) from my Drive to a spreadsheet using Google Apps Script. The problem is that I don't know how to add content to rows of a Google Sheets document.

I know how to log my files and their Id:

```
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    Logger.log(file.getId());
}
```

Now I would like to log the Name and Id of my files from one folder to a Google sheet. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the spreadsheet, and add the file names to a 2D array.  The following code requires you to enter the spreadsheet file ID and the sheet tab name.

```
function logFilesToSheet() {
  var arrayForOneRow,file,id,name,outerArray,sh,ss;

  id = "";//Enter your spreadsheet file id here
  name = "";//Enter the sheet tab name here

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);

  outerArray = [];

  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();

    //Logger.log(file.getName());
    //Logger.log(file.getId());

    arrayForOneRow = [];//Reset on each loop - Each row needs a new array

    arrayForOneRow.push(file.getName());
    arrayForOneRow.push(file.getId());

    outerArray.push(arrayForOneRow);
  }

  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1,outerArray.length,2).setValues(outerArray);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I can't get the code to work. It exports this (with different numbers at the end): [Ljava.lang.Object;@7742d5f7. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Also, I would like to add the name to one column and the Id to a different column if this is possible?

Comment: The ` [Ljava.lang.Object;@7742d5f7` means that it's an object that didn't get converted to a string.  Are you seeing that in the logs or in the spreadsheet?  I changed the answer to include both the name and ID.

Comment: I made a mistake.  appendRow takes a 1D array, and I created a 2D array.  See the new answer.  If this answered your question, you can click the green check mark.

Comment: Thanks for updating! I will click the green check mark when this works but this error message appears when I execute the script: ` Exception: Cannot convert 'function () { [native code] }1' to int. (line 28, file "Code") ` Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I fixed the error.  The parenthesis were missing from `sh.getLastRow()`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.